# Angularjs Ui-Bootstrap modal popup inside specified element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have a problem with my code , this code is about append a modal to element with specific id. so that when button clicked ,this modal popup will showed inside div element with id="forModal" (div element with this id is inside view.html) ,my app using angularjs that have base html(index.html) ,one template for route(view.html),one template for modal(modal.html).

**index.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <!--Ui Route-->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.min.js"> </script>

  <!--UI Bootstrap-->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.min.js"></script>

  <!--UI Bootstrap TPLS-->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-2.5.0-tpls.min.js"></script>

  <!--ngCoockies-->
  <script src="js/angular-cookies.js"></script>

  <!-- my app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  <!--controller js-->
  <script src="js/controller.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body ng-app="starter">
   <ui-view></ui-view>
 </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var moduleapp = angular.module('starter',  ['ionic','ui.router','ngCookies','ui.bootstrap']);

moduleapp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider.state("dashboard",{
    url:"/dashboard",
    templateUrl:"templates/dashboard.html",
    controller : "dashboardCtrl"
  })

 $stateProvider.state("dashboard.view",{
    url : "/view",
    templateUrl : "templates/view.html",
    controller: "viewDataCtrl"
  })
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard.view")
 })
```

**controller.js**

```
moduleapp.controller('dashboardCtrl',[function(){
 //some code 
}])

moduleapp.controller('viewDataCtrl',['$document','$uibModal','$scope','$http','$cookies',function($document,$uibModal,$scope,$http,$cookies){

// reserve variable,declare it as object
$scope.dataColumn = {};
$scope.dataData = {};

// reserve variable for user authetication level
$scope.userLevel= $cookies.get('userLevel');

//function for finding available column
function caricolumn(){
 $http.get('link for search column.php').success(function(hasil){
   $scope.dataColumn = hasil;
 });
}

//executing function when controller running
caricolumn();

//function for get data,return result to $scope.dataData as object
function caridata(){
  $http.get('link for search data.php').success(function(hasil){
   $scope.dataData = hasil;
 })
}

//execute function when controller running
caridata();
//function for edit
$scope.edit = function(x){
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl:'templates/modal.html',
  controller:'viewDataCtrl',
  //THIS IS THE PROBLEM ,appendTO doesnt work,still inject modal popup to body element
  appendTo : angular.element(document.querySelector('#viewElement'))
 });
}
//function for delete data
 $scope.delete = function(x){
 $http.post('link for deletedata.php',x).success(function(hasil){
   alert(hasil);
   //if output(php echo) same as string ,this condition considered as success
   if(hasil == "Delete Success"){
     caridata();
   }
  })
 }
}]);
```

**modal.html**

```
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h3>Hayy</h3>
  </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
   <p>this is Body</p>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   this is footer
 </div>
```

**dashboard.html**

```
 <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
   <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
     <ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-back-button>

     <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
     <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
     </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ui-view>
  <!--This is where view.html injected-->
  </ui-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
   <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
 </ion-header-bar>
 <ion-content>
   <ion-list ><a ui-sref="dashboard.add">
     <ion-item>Tambah Data</ion-item></a>
   </ion-list>
   <ion-list ><a ui-sref="dashboard.view">
    <ion-item>Tampil Data</ion-item></a>
   </ion-list>
  <ion-list >
    <a ng-click="logout()">
     <ion-item>Log Out</ion-item>
    </a>
   </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**view.html**

```
<div id="viewElement" class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
 <h2>Data-Data</h2>
 <hr/>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="dc in dataColumn">{{dc.KOLOM}}</th>
    <th ng-if="userLevel == 'LV02' || userLevel == 'LV01'">Edit</th>
    <th ng-if="userLevel == 'LV01'">Delete</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="dd in dataData" id="dt{{dd.IDROW}}">
    <td ng-repeat="ddd in dd.DATA">{{ddd}}</td>
    <td ng-if="userLevel == 'LV01' || userLevel == 'LV01'"><button type="button" ng-click="edit({{dd.IDROW}})" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button></td>
    <td ng-if="userLevel == 'LV01'"><button type="button" ng-click="delete({{dd.IDROW}})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

as you can see ,when app running .route default will go to "dashboard.view"
dashboard state is code for left sidemenu ,then dashboard.view state for viewing data(view state in child from dashboard state)
what i want is when edit button clicked inside view.html(controller : viewDataCtrl,state : dashboard.view), modal popup will appear inside div element with id="forModal" (div element with this id is inside view.html)
but with this code ,modal popup always appear inside body tag element not inside div element with id="forModal".
how can i approach this condition ? thanks

Comment: You have two elements with `id="viewElement"`, one in `modal.html` and the other in `view.html`. That's not going to work well

Comment: Any errors in your console? Specifically, [this error](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L699)?

Comment: Also, how are you confirming that the modal is appended to `<body>`? Looking at their code, it doesn't seem possible to set an `appendTo` property and have it continue to append the modal to the default `<body>` tag

Comment: sory sir ,im already edit this post . the code before is not right.please see the updated post sir .thanks sir . @Phil

Comment: One more thing, don't include both `ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.min.js` **and** `ui-bootstrap-2.5.0-tpls.min.js`. The latter is a super-set of the former

Comment: silly me.this code already inject to right div .it look like my problem is this targeted div DOM is not right . thanks @Phil .your'e the best haha

Comment: im incuding this ui-bootstrap-2.5.0-tpls.min.js is for fixing "Failed to load template: uib/template/modal/window.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)".it happen when templateurl parameter incluede in $.uibmodal.open() placed @Phil

Comment: Yes, if you include the latter, you do not need the former

Comment: ahaha thanks sirr .you save me again haha .i'll fix this code .i appreciate it sir.thanks for all of your help @Phil